# Proof that $(\alpha I - A)$ invertible if $\alpha > \rho(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to proof that for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $a_{ij}\geq 0, \forall i,j=1,...,n$:

\begin{align}
(\alpha I - A) \text{ is invertible if } \alpha > \rho(A)
\end{align}
where $\rho(A)$ ist the spectral radius of $A$, so the largest eigen value of A.

I want to show that $\det(\alpha I - A) \neq 0$, but I don't know how. What I found out so far is that $\det(A)=\lambda_1^{r_i}...\lambda_n^{r_n} \leq \rho(A)^{r_i}...\rho(A)^{r_n}$ and that $\det(\alpha I)=\alpha^n$. Can I use this somehow?

I know this has a lot to do with functional analysis. $(\alpha I - A)^{-1}$ is the resolvent formalism. But I never had anything to do with functional analysis, so I'm struggling.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really need to get into Functional Analysis for this. It just has to do with the definition of eigenvalue.

Suppose that $\alpha$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. If $(\alpha I-A)x=0$, then $Ax=\alpha x$; but then $x=0$ (otherwise $\alpha$ would be an eigenvalue). So the kernel of $\alpha I-A$ is trivial, which makes $\alpha I-A$ invertible.

Comment: Nice.${{{{}}}}$

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler than you're thinking...consider what the modulus of $(\alpha I - A)x$ could be.